# Using jquery ui dialog with tooltip causes tooltip display on opening, not hover

Tags: jquery-ui

I set up the tooltip and dialog like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( document ).tooltip();
```

but when i open the dialog later its close tooltip always appears on opening, NOT just on hovering over close as expected. Has anyone else seen this behaviour/knows why it occurs?

Answer (score 7):

Setting the `items` option to exclude the dialog's titlebar close widget seems to work well for me in jQueryUI 1.9+

```
$( document ).tooltip({
  items: '*:not(.ui-dialog-titlebar-close)'
});
```

Comment: The slove problem for dialog-ui bug, but there is another bug : http://jsfiddle.net/5renLfmp/2/ all tooltips aren't working. If you do just tooltip() call without filter, it's works. So how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

```
$( "*" ).tooltip();
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').tooltip('disable')
```

works in place of the above

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip appears because a button automatically gets focus when a dialog opens (this is a strange behavior). You need to add an attribute "tabindex" to any element in the dialog to avoid this.

For example:

```
<table tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Thanks @riks. Just added tabindex=1 on one of the elements and dont see the auto popup anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [dialog's documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/):

> Upon opening a dialog, focus is automatically moved to the first item
>   that matches the following:
>
> - The first element within the dialog with the autofocus attribute
> - The first :tabbable element within the dialog's content
> - The first :tabbable element within the dialog's buttonpane
> - The dialog's close button
> - The dialog itself

So my solution was to add `autofocus` to an empty div at the top of the form I was using in my dialog:

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="stealFocus" autofocus></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution for me with 1.11.3 jQuery and 1.10.4 jUI

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._focusTabbable = function(){};
```

It will desactivate autofocus and dont see auto popup anymore

Answer (score 0):

I use :

$( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeText: "" });